# Callback function not working in Axios javascript

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

Im trying to make a register form with VueJS and Axios and Laravel.
I've written the following shortcut function to make a post request and handle laravel form validations errors:

```
window.post = function (vueResource, url, data, responseCallback){

let _rsrc = vueResource;
let _data = vueResource.$data;

if(data !== ''){
    _data = data;
}

axios.post(url, _data).then(responseCallback).catch(function(error){
      if(error.response.status == 422){
          _rsrc.errors = error.response.data.errors;
          return false;
      }
      throw error;
});
}
```

Now when i make a post request, using the following code:

```
 post(this,'/api/register','',function(response){
        alert(1);
 });
```

The request is done, a user is created, but the callback function is not executed. There's no alert.

Why is this not working?

Comment: Your code looks correct. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Not getting any errors

Comment: Then probably it is not getting a response, and there is a timeout.

Comment: When i inspect my network tab, i can see the returned data, it also gives a 200 status

Comment: It works for me. check here https://jsfiddle.net/gk5b7wty/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me.

```js
let dataMock =   {
    "title": "SOme title",
    "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
  }

post = function (vueResource, url, data, responseCallback){

axios.post(url, vueResource).then(responseCallback).catch(function(error){
      if(error.response.status == 422){
          _rsrc.errors = error.response.data.errors;
          return false;
      }
      throw error;
});
}

post(dataMock,'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts','',function(response){
        alert(1);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.17.1/axios.js"></script>
```

Try doing a console.log instead. I am guessing you have disables the alert popups.

Make sure you have not disables the alert popups and try again

Comment: I'm an idiot, JS didn't compile. Thanks for your time!